# Combined debug and release compilation

Tags: c++, windows, qt, release-mode, debug-mode

I have a Qt project where I compile 2 DLL libraries and 1 EXE executable. The EXE file uses the DLL's.

When I compile the DLL's in *debug mode* and the EXE in *release mode*, there is a problem; the application doesn't start and instead says that the `QWidget` object must be created when `QApllication` object is already created.

When all projects are built in release mode, there's *no* problem.

Why do I have this error? What difference is there between **debug** and **release** mode that causes the problem?

Here is the code of .exe:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication BlocksManager(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));

    //LoginDialog authWidget;
    //if (authWidget.exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
        //return 0;

    Leos *initOb = new Leos;
    createTrees(*initOb);

    BlocksWidget wgt(initOb, NULL);
    delete initOb;
    return BlocksManager.exec();
}
```

Comment: The heap manager is not the same, because debug builds do not use the same runtime as release builds. This may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: But why does it change the order of instructions? I create QWidget object after creating QApllication object. And it works right if all builds are release or debug. Otherwise, if i combine debug and release builds the order of creating objects is changed. Why?

Comment: Depends on how you create them. Are they static instances initialized in global scope?

Comment: I have already checked it, no, I don't use static objects at all, all of them are defined in local scope. I'v added the code.

Comment: Yes, you do use static objects. When you create the application object, then Qt stores a pointer to the application object in a global variable, and uses that pointer to access to application object. Not sure if that is the problem though.

Comment: But it's only a pointer, not an inctance itself. And the constructor is'n called when pointer initializes, right?